# Extern variables aren't initialized

Tags: c++, initialization, global, extern

In a project I am doing I use some global variables using "extern" so that all files can access them.

The following is my case:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"


std::string val2 = val;



int main()
{
    std::cout << val2 << std::endl;
}
```

test.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

extern std::string val;
```

test.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"

std::string val = "Hello World";
```

And what I am expecting to get as output is "Hello World" however it will just print a new line.

If instead of std::string I use a built-in type (like int) it will work as expected.

From my understanding, what happens is `val` has not been initialized when we are trying to assign it to `val2`, so we end up copying nothing, then after that (probably) `val` gets initialized with the value `Hello World` but since we are printing `val2` we get only the new line.

So my question is, How can I force `val` to initialize first.

If that's not possible, how can I make global variables (that can be used between multiple files)

***NOTE***: Those are not my real files but I checked and the problem appears here as well, I think this counts as a Minimal Code Example (or whatever it is called)

Comment: cant get a link right now but: static initialization order fiasco.

Comment: There are tons of questions on StackOverflow about SIOF, a simple search will turn up many.

Comment: @RemyLebeau sorry, I didn't even know what that's called and I tried to search but didn't find anything (obviously because I didn't know what to search for)

Comment: https://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/static-init-order.html

Comment: It's never too soon to stop using global variables.